# A 3d integral over a ball

Tags: integration, 3d

Given $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $r>0$, is it possible to compute
$$\int_{B_r(a)} \frac{a\cdot x}{|x|^3} dx$$

where $B_r(a)$ is the ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with radius $r$ and centered at $a$.

Comment: Could you please be more precise in your notation? Is $x$ a vector and $dx = dV$? Substituting spherical coordinates should work.

Comment: if that doesnt work try stokes (or one of its various variants)

Comment: x denote a vector or is the component x?. I tell you that, because  you write a "$dx$" instead "$dv$"

Comment: Sorry, yes $x$ is a vector and $dx$ is $dV$. Also $\cdot$ denotes scalar product.

Comment: I guess "$a$" is a vector, too.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes, that one I didn't forget to mention in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\iiint_{\verts{\vec{R} - \vec{a}} < r}\
{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{R} \over R^{3}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{R}} & =
\vec{a}\cdot\iiint_{R < r}\
{\vec{R} + \vec{a}\over \verts{\vec{R} + \vec{a}}^{3}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{R} =
-\vec{a}\cdot\iiint_{R < r}\
{\vec{R} - \vec{a} \over \verts{\vec{R} - \vec{a}}^{3}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{R}
\\[3mm] & =
\vec{a}\cdot\nabla_{\vec{a}}\iiint_{R < r}\
{\dd^{3}\vec{R} \over \verts{\vec{R} - \vec{a}}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

In general; we can consider, for simplicity, the case of $\vec{a}$ along the $z$-axis $\pars{~\vec{a} = \verts{\vec{a}}\hat{z} = a\hat{z}~}$. We'll recover the general result at the very end. Then,
\begin{align}
\iiint_{R < r}\
{\dd^{3}\vec{R} \over \verts{\vec{R} - \vec{a}}} & =
2\pi\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over \root{R^{2} - 2Ra\cos\pars{\theta} + a^{2}}}
\,R^{2}\,\dd R
\\[3mm] & =
2\pi\int_{0}^{r}\int_{-1}^{1}
{\dd\xi \over \root{R^{2} - 2Ra\xi + a^{2}}}\,R^{2}\,\dd R
\\[3mm] & =
2\pi\int_{0}^{r}\left.{\root{R^{2} - 2Ra\xi + a^{2}} \over -Ra}
\right\vert_{\ \xi\ =\ -1}^{\ \xi\ =\ 1}\,R^{2}\,\dd R
\\[3mm] & =
{2\pi \over a}\int_{0}^{r}\bracks{%
{\root{R^{2} + 2Ra + a^{2}} - {\root{R^{2} - 2Ra + a^{2}}}}}\,R\,\dd R
\\[3mm] & =
{2\pi \over a}\int_{0}^{r}\pars{R + a - \verts{R - a}}\,R\,\dd R =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{{4\pi r^{3} \over 3}\,{1 \over a}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r < a}
\\[2mm]
\ds{2\pi\pars{r^{2} - {1 \over 3}\,a^{2}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r \geq a}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
and
$$
\nabla_{\vec{a}}\iiint_{R < r}\
{\dd^{3}\vec{R} \over \verts{\vec{R} - \vec{a}}} =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{-\,{4\pi r^{3} \over 3}\,{\vec{a} \over a^{3}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r < a}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-\,{4\pi \over 3}\,\vec{a}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r \geq a}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

With the result $\pars{1}$:
$$\color{#f00}{\iiint_{\verts{\vec{R} - \vec{a}} < r}\
{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{R} \over R^{3}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{R}} =
\color{#f00}{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{-\,{4\pi r^{3} \over 3}\,{1 \over a}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r < a}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-\,{4\pi \over 3}\,a^{2}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r \geq a}
\end{array}\right.}
$$